# WordPress get_tags() ingoring orderby

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using get_tags() to get all my tags and display them paginated on a page.

I can get the tags no problem and 'number' and 'offset' arguments work exactly as expected, but for some reason the 'orderby' and 'order' arguments seem to be getting ignored.

Here's the code:

```
$tags = get_tags(
    array( 
        'number' => $tags_per_page, 
        'offset' => $offset, 
        'orderby' => 'count', 
        'order' => 'DESC' 
    )
);
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
}
```

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Please post your code in your question

Comment: Apologies, have edited the post to include the code directly.